# My site has been attacked by fake visitors

Tags: spam, visitors

My Website is phonel.ir. My site has been attacked by fake visitors (IP Spam)
Look at the picture below:
[image]
But Google's click reports are correct:
[image]
Are these attacks harmful to my site?
Can my site be penalized on Google?

Comment: "Are these attacks harmful to my site?" Does your site run exploitable software?

Comment: @102764 Car videos are displayed on my site. Looks like youtube

Comment: Are these reports from Google Analytics, Google Search Console, or somewhere else?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller How do I report these to Google?

Comment: Can you include some access_log entries for these IP addresses? It is impossible to say what is going on from the information you supplied. You may want to consider installing mod_security or fail2ban to block unwanted traffic. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc These IPs want to access two urls: "/wp-login.php" and "/xmlrpc.php". My site is newly established. So visitors come in via Google. But these IPs go directly to my site.
They don't come from a site like Google or Bing. My site is Farsi but they are from different countries (China, Singapore, USA, India, UK, Japan and etc)

Comment: Okay. These are landscape attempts or hack attempts from scripts that are running on systems that already have been compromised. If these files do not exist, you are not in any danger. However, you may want to block these IP addresses using .htaccess (assuming Apache). I would still recommend mod_security or fail2ban to automatically block most if not all bad actors. Cheers!!

Comment: @tooraj I'm not asking you to report these to Google.  I'm asking where you are getting these graphs.   If they are from search console, you would react to these very differently than if it data from analytics.